# rspec - PG::UnableToSend:server closed the connection unexpectedly This probably means the server terminated abnormally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

On my ruby on Rails app, when creating a model Deal, I use an after_create to create prizes on the DealPrize table.

Deal and DealPrize have a belong to/has_many relations: a Deal has many Deal prizes and a Dealprize belongs to a Deal.

It works like this: on my admin panel (using activeadmin), inside a Deal, I have a column 'prize-number' and I use an after_create so that every time the admin creates a new deal, the app takes this prize_number column, and create this volume of prizes (inserting as many rows as necessary) inside the DealPrize table.

**My tests using rspec and FactoryGirl are failing. It might be due to the fact rspec/factory girl do not play well with prepared_statements.** I am not sure.

Here is my code

**models/deal.rb**

```
has_many :deal_prizes, dependent: :delete_all

after_create :create_dealprizes

# Constants
TIME_SET = Time.zone.now
CONNECTION = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection

def create_dealprizes
  begin 
    CONNECTION.describe_prepared('create_deal_prizes')
  rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName
    CONNECTION.prepare('create_deal_prizes', 'INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id,created_at,updated_at,admin_user_id,prize_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)') 
  end

  Deal.transaction do  
    self.prizes_number.times do |i| 
      CONNECTION.exec_prepared('create_deal_prizes',  [
        { value: self.id},
        { value: TIME_SET },
        { value: TIME_SET },
        { value: self.admin_user_id },
        { value: 5 }
      ])
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my test: I would like to be sure when a deal is created that if the deal's prizes_number is 340 then 340 rows are added on the table Dealprizes as it should be.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe DealPrize do
  describe "the right number of rows are created inside DealPrize table when a Deal is created" do

    before do 
      @initial_prize_count = DealPrize.count
      @deal_prize = FactoryGirl.create(:deal_prize) 
      @deal       = FactoryGirl.create(:deal_prizes => [@deal_prize], :prizes_number => 277)
    end

    it "does create right nb of rows" do
      expect(DealPrize.count).to eq( @initial_prize_count + 277 )
    end
  end
end
```

I use a factory for Deals:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :deal do
    country       "France"
    title         "Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem"
    description   "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"

    factory :deal_skips_validate do
      to_create {|instance| instance.save(validate: false) }
    end    

  end
end
```

and here is the Factory for DealPrizes:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :deal_prize do
  end
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
PG::UnableToSend:
       server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.
```

If needed, here is how I deal with transaction in my spec_helper.rb

```
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.before(:suite) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, :except => %w(roles)) 
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:each, js: true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

config.before(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

config.after(:each) do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Comment: Your FactoryGirl usage does not look correct. What FG version are you using?

Comment: edited the code of factory girl because some part was not right.

Comment: using the latest version of 'gem 'factory_girl_rails'  gem. in my 'gem list' I can read: factory_girl (4.5.0, 4.4.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.5.0, 4.4.1, 4.4.0)

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to do with the postgresql transaction not playing well in rspec, or some need to disconnect it...

Comment: Any reason you are creating 340 inserts instead of one? Thinking that can be done in 1 query. Any reason you are using a prepared_statement rather than just plain ol' SQL? Don't see anything special, which is why I ask. Just curious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to grab a new connection from the pool each time your method runs (and make sure you return it to the pool when you're done). Take a look at [with_connection](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html).

Something like this should work.

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_prizes, dependent: :delete_all

  after_create :create_dealprizes

  # Constants
  TIME_SET = Time.zone.now

  def create_dealprizes
    self.class.connection_pool.with_connection do |connection|
      begin 
        connection.describe_prepared('create_deal_prizes')
      rescue PG::InvalidSqlStatementName
        connection.prepare('create_deal_prizes', 'INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id,created_at,updated_at,admin_user_id,prize_id) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)') 
      end

      connection.execute("START TRANSACTION")
      prizes_number.times do |i| 
        connection.exec_prepared('create_deal_prizes',  [
          { value: self.id},
          { value: TIME_SET },
          { value: TIME_SET },
          { value: self.admin_user_id },
          { value: 5 }
        ])
      end
      connection.execute("COMMIT")
    end
  end
end
```

This should work, but in my opinion (for what it's worth) it's not very Ruby-ish.  It sounds like you're concerned with performance, so I would add the data with a single INSERT statement. You could build that manually, but the [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem makes it very easy.

Using that gem might look something like:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_prizes, dependent: :delete_all

  after_create :create_dealprizes

  def create_dealprizes
    prizes = prizes_number.times.map do
               deal_prizes.build(created_by: admin_user, prize_id: 5)
             end
    DealPrize.import(prizes)
  end
end
```

Here's a [sample app](https://github.com/masonjm/after-create-demo) that uses ActiveRecord import.

Comment: hi James will try that. If you help, your opinion matters :) So I'll try your second proposed solution the activerecord-import. I has actuall seen this gem BUT it was not obvious for me what it did: I thought it was to import csv data and things like this, and not transfer data from one table to another table. I guess I was wrong. And yes performance is very important as prizes_number can equal 400,000 :)

Comment: It's not working. It's not creating any deal_prizes. There was "times" in your code that was not necessary , I remove dit but still nothing happens. I'm not getting any error, it's just that when the Deal is created, I go see the table DealPrizes and no rows have been added. I removed all the validations in my model to be sure it was not the cause. I read this: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Callbacks => so as I am using a callback, i might not be able to use activerecord-import inside the callback ?

Comment: Sorry about the bug. Don't code tired, eh? Check your logs. You should see `Class Create Many Without Validations Or Callbacks` if the import is running. You can also add some log statements to the callback to make sure the method is being run. The Callbacks doc is referring to callbacks on `DealPrize`, so it shouldn't be relevant in this case.

Comment: hehe gettting a little tired, but let's push! I use excatly your code but sitll same thing: Deal is created but nothing happens for DealPrizes(they don't get created). btw I replaced your .build (I was getting error "undefined method `build' ") by 'create'. But still same problem. I don't see in my Local logs "Class Create Many Without Validations Or Callbacks" nothing. it's like active record is not activated. As I said before maybe it wo'nt work in a callback: https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Callbacks. What do you think ?

Comment: hi, not giving up but i am trying now your non-rubyish way: I am getting an error: "undefined method `describe_prepared' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter:0x00000008c44ea8>"

Comment: No clue what that error means. I've added a link to a sample application that uses ActiveRecord import. You can try comparing your code to that, and see what you've got that's causing it to break. I'd highly recommend added debug statements so you can see what's happening (see the sample app).

Answer (score 1):

You only retrieve `CONNECTION` from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.raw_connection` once, as the class is being loaded. So the framework is free to close that connection and create a new one. You should retrieve it at the time you actually need it, then I imagine it might work.

Update: afaik the PostgreSQL adapter will create prepared statements, too and the database should be able to re-use them, so the performance gain from doing these things manually shouldn't be that big (especially since you're "only" talking about a few hundred objects). You lose compatibility to other adapters as well as maintainability due to non-idiomatic Rails code when you could just create DealPrize objects instead.

Comment: sorry but rookie here with postgresql, how would you code this ?

Comment: Just replace `CONNECTION` with `self.class.connection.raw_connection`, that should do the trick.

Comment: no I'm using transactions because i'm creating about 500000 every time I create with my admin panel dela prizes

Comment: could you provide a way while keeping to use this exec_prepared and raw sql that I am applying in deal.rb that I have really tought through. My problem now is how to make test work.

Comment: ok, in that case the manually prepared statement might make sense. But then it might also be advisable to make this work asynchronous. Use a Sidekiq worker or ActiveJob, depending on your Rails version, that way you don't need to do it inline.

Comment: Actually the test failing is just one symptom. There are other situations like connection pooling or other techniques that might break the code, too. If you think this code is working correctly, you probably just have been lucky until now or haven't run the app for long enough.

Comment: haha 2nd option probably (haven't run the app for long enough) ! So what would you do? I heard about sidekicq but I was intending to use it for "background jobs" ie like for emails, and background cron/routines. But here when I create those 500K deal_prizes as an admin, I don't want them to go at the end of a possible already large queue of tasks: I need them to be done RIGHT AWAY. It seemed to me that in that case, sidekicq as a background job tool was not the right tool.

Comment: when I use your suggestion "replace CONNECTION with self.class.connection.raw_connection", I get an Error: app/models/deal.rb:317:in `<class:Deal>': undefined method `connection' for Class:Class (NoMethodError)

Comment: Sorry, must have been late yesterday already ^^ Just `connection.raw_connection` should suffice.

Comment: doesn't work either. actually, what's strange is that when I test it on sublime, the first time the database does not hang up, but if I remake the test  second time it hangs up.

Answer (score 1):

Can I suggest the following?

```
def create_deal_prizes
  batch_size = 1000
  deal_prizes = []
  time = Time.zone.now
  prize_id = 5 # wasn't sure where you got this id from

  Deal.transaction do
    deal_prizes = []
    prizes_number.times do
      deal_prizes << "(#{self.id}, #{self.admin_user_id}, #{prize_id}, '#{time}', '#{time}')"

      if deal_prizes.size >= batch_size
        sql = "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, admin_user_id, prize_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{deal_prizes.join(", ")}"
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql
        deal_prizes = []
      end
    end
    if deal_prizes.any?
      sql = "INSERT INTO deal_prizes (deal_id, admin_user_id, prize_id, created_at, updated_at) VALUES #{deal_prizes.join(", ")}"
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute sql
    end
  end
end
```

This is more rails-esque, efficient, and won't have to be re-written when you switch to [INSERT DB HERE]. Feel free to play with the batch_size as well.

Another note, almost positive if you set the time to a constant it will not change, was that your intention? Instead I moved it to the method, so it will lock to the time it was invoked and not the time the class was initialized (boot).

Comment: thanks for your answer. i went the transaction +raw sql way based on this benchmark ( https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/ quite old article though). because each deal create i need to add like 400k to 500k deal prizes. but it's true way is more rail- sy but you don't change obtenir your db type right? i'll try your suggestion and compare speed. and yes u're right better put time inside method!

Comment: meant to say one thing u dont change often is your db type.

Comment: That's great that you are benchmarking. And that is true, how often do you change your db. I would imagine from a scaling perspective, the bulk inserts would be better, especially if it's competing with other DB operations happening on your site. So you should take that into consideration even more than the speed, which I'd imagine they would end up pretty close?

Comment: just to be clear as I'm a rookie. yes the query will be cometing with many other queries on the same db coming from other users. so you say bulk is more suited. what is exactly ,bulk inserts' for you? transactions? one single mass raw sql insert without transactions?

Comment: or maybe by 'bul inserts' you mean what you suggested, the tactic with batch imports?

Comment: So instead of doing n x sql inserts or procedure executions, you are doing n / batch_size x sql inserts (or procedures). You said sometimes you do 500,000 prizes? That would mean 500,000 inserts in your case.... If you have a batch size of 1000, that would be 500 inserts, each with 1000 records at a time.... 500 is probably better than 500,000, and you can still wrap it in a transaction.

Comment: tried it but it does not work. Deal prizes are just not added to the Deal Prize table. I think, it's because on your code nothing telles Rails to put them inside the Deal Prize table vs the original code where I said 'connection.prepare('create_deal_prizes', 'INSERT INTO deal_prizes'

Comment: The `self.deal_prizes.create(deal_prizes)` is what creates the rows, but you are right, because it's in transactions it won't fire them. You could remove that part just to see it work.

Comment: you have proposed 'self.deal_prizes.create(deal_prizes)' in 2 different lines. I tried commenting out the first one, did not work, ; then the second one, did not work either, and even both of them, did not work... :(

Comment: I did it twice in the event the last deal_prizes falls below the batch_size threshold. In the event you had say 1500 prizes, the first 1000 will get created, but the remaining 500 since it's less than 1000 would not for the first call, and is handled by second call. Check my edit and tell me if that works.

Comment: Still the same with the new code (seems you removed the transaction). Deal is created but not the associated Deal prizes: it does not generate the Deal prizes rows inside Deal Prize table. in my console, I don't see any error, it's just that Deal is created and nothing happens/is triggered as regards Deal_prizes

Comment: Not sure whats going on... Validations? I'd need to see the app to trully debug. A great article: (https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) What you are doing is like Option 2. I'm suggesting a variant of Option 3, just using AR. James is recommending Option 4. As you can see by the benchmark, a fushion of mine and your solutions will yield the best result: bulk raw sql. If you want I can modify my answer to show you how to do that.

Comment: that would be great! i tried once bulk raw sql but it was working only for sql not postgresql so would be grateful for your help

Comment: on your latest code version, you use 'conn', but I don't see it defined.

Comment: Updated just now. Bad copy/paste